# Magento attribute filter using 'like' not functioning as expected

Tags: php, magento

I am having a problem with `addAttributeToFilter()` where it is not working as I expect.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
...snip...
$simple_associated_collection = $product->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('like'=>$configurable_product_sku.'_%'))
  ->load();
```

Passing in `4_%` I expect to get

```
4_1
4_2
```

But I also get

```
42_1
420_1
```

The goal is to get a collection of simple products so that I can associate them with their configurable parent after an import.

How should I be using `LIKE` to get the same results I would in `MySQL`?

Comment: You can debug your SQL statement by calling `echo $simple_associated_collection->getSelect()->assemble()`.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, that was showing SQL I expected and results I didn't `_` is a wildcard character (simple google brings that up now!). fixed with `\_`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento was not at fault here, `_` is a wildcard character.

I used Nick's comment to echo the sql which was what I expected.

Fixed:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('like'=>$configurable_product_sku.'\_%'))
```

Answer (score -1):

example

```
->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('like'=>$configurable_product_sku.'_'.'%'))
```